# How to make http request in AngularJS for give JSON data formate?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to make angularjs app to make http request,I make the following code (index.html)to make http request of JSON data using angularjs. But it is not printing the json data.

In console of firefox I am getting the **following warning(same origin**
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/metering/samples?meter=instance&group_by=project&stats_attr=avg&date_options=7&date_from=&date_to=. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

I have josn data in following formate. 
URL is 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/metering/samples?meter=instance&group_by=project&stats_attr=avg&date_options=7&date_from=&date_to=

```
{
    "series": [
        {
            "meter": "instance",
            "data": [
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-17T09:52:17"
                },
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-18T09:57:40"
                },
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-19T09:55:29"
                },
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-20T09:59:43"
                },
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-21T05:35:26"
                },
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-22T09:56:47"
                },
                {
                    "y": 1,
                    "x": "2015-06-23T09:55:07"
                }
            ],
            "name": "demo",
            "unit": "instance"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

 <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="value in meters">
        {{value.x+','+value.y}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/metering/samples?meter=instance&group_by=project&stats_attr=avg&date_options=7&date_from=&date_to=")
        .success(function(response) {
          console.log(response.series[0].data)
          $scope.meters = response.series[0].data;
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please check my plunker it may help :)

Answer (score 0):

Typo:- change `myyApp to myapp`

```
 var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Some logical problem also been fixed please check plunker.

Change  `$scope.meters=response.records`; to `$scope.meters=response.series[0].data;`

ng-repeat should be like:-

```
<li ng-repeat="value in meters">
                         {{value.x+','+value.y}}
                    </li>
```

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yuZhmypTE7Js9rMxvyc0?p=preview)

Comment: Yes your code is working in when I make file name "data.json" in my local system. But same code is not working when I replace "data.json" with url. Please see my url in question, this is the same user which is give json data, please help me on this, thanks...........

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading @squiroid  I am getting this working `the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/metering/samples?meter=instance&group_by=project&stats_attr=avg&date_options=7&date_from=&date_to=. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).'

Comment: tell me about your server which language you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
 var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="value in meters.series.data">
{{value.x}} -- {{value.y}}
</li>
```